# ASP.NET Custom Validator On 2 Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I know I can use the below syntax to validate the field txtfirstname against the database, but what if I needed to take it a step further and validate both txtfirstname and txtlastname against the database, what would I tweak in order to only present an error if BOTH values alreadyd exist in the database?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfirstname"
        ErrorMessage="Please input a valid first name" Height="21px" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"
        Width="154px">Please input first name</asp:CustomValidator><br />


protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;
    string fname = txtfirstname.Text;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from usertable where usertable.firstname=@fn", conn);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@fn");
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@fn"].Value = fname;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        args.IsValid = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply retrieve the value for the last name field and do the same validation as you are doing it for the first name:

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
        string fname = txtfirstname.Text;
        string lname = txtlastname.Text; // Get the last name
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from usertable where usertable.firstname=@fn and usertable.lastname=@ln", conn); // Add last name to query
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@fn");
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@fn"].Value = fname;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ln"); // New parameter.
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters["@ln"].Value = lname;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            args.IsValid = true;

    }
```

Please note that I updated your code and I suppose the name of the last name fields. Please test it in your code and update it if needed according to your objects.

Also, I suggest you not to do a "Select *" because it's not a good practice for performance. Simply check for a single field.